# Ubuntu 20.04 After Fingerprint login, password request to unlock the desktop

Tags: login, password, fingerprint-reader, keyrings, gnome-keyring

I have this issue with fingerprint.

Almost all works fine, I can use it for elevate privileges, I can login .... but 
just after passed the login screen, when the desktop appears, I have a pop up window asking for input the use password, since the keyring was not unlocked.

I done the setup procedure several times, but still have the same issue.

I have also done sudo pam-auth-update, but it didn't help.

I think is something in a config file, before with another distro was working fine, but I have no idea where to look for.

Thank in advance for your support

Eld